# How can I type hint only some parameters of an @abstractmethod?

Tags: python, type-hinting

In an abstract method declaration, how can I specify that ex. the first parameter must be of a certain type, but any subclass's implementation may have additional parameters that are of `Any` type?

I know that cascading type annotations from the parameter declarations in an `abstractmethod` down to a subclass's implementation of that method is not possible (though it's been [discussed at length](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3903)), but that is not my question. The problem is not that I want to avoid re-writing type hints in the subclass. See below my situation:

```
from typing import Any
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Wheel: pass

class Bike(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def update(self, front_wheel: Wheel, back_wheel: Wheel, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any): pass
    # ^ Same issue when using *args: Optional[Any], **kwargs: Optional[Any]

class Unicycle(Bike):  # (for example)
    def update(self, front_wheel: Wheel):  # Fails typecheck, as expected
        ...

class Bicycle(Bike):
    def update(self, front_wheel: Wheel, back_wheel: Wheel):  # Fails typecheck, but I want it to pass
        ...

class Motorcycle(Bike):
    def update(self, front_wheel: Wheel, back_wheel: Wheel, gas_left: float):  # Fails typecheck, but I want it to pass
        ...
```

If I remove `*args` and `**kwargs` as params from the `abstractmethod` declaration, then `Bicycle` passes the typecheck, but `Unicycle` and `Motorcycle` fail.

What am I missing?

**System details:**

- Pycharm Professional Build #PY-213.7172.26
- [Mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) latest version 0.961

Comment: Suppose you could get away with what you wanted to do. A function is written that handles a generic `Bike` object without knowing whether it's a `Bicycle`, `Motorcycle`, or whatnot. How is it going to handle a call to `update()` if that call can have different numbers of arguments depending on whether the `Bike` is really a `Bicycle` or a `Motorcycle`?

Comment: @jjramsey Simply check the type (`isinstance`). It's not a problem for the interpreter, it is only manifesting as a problem for type hinting. The typechecker should even be able to see, within in an `if` block checking ex. `isinstance(b, Motorcycle)`, that any calls to `b.update()` need the exact parameter types required by `Motorcycle`.

Comment: [^ Proof](https://gist.github.com/jacksonthall22/87cb3153f063a863d049051be2e9b844)

Comment: if you're trying to do this, then `update` shouldn't be a method on your abstract class . I think you're modelling your domain wrong in some way, though I can't say how without thinking a lot more about it. Using `isinstance` is often a sign of this, especially if you're using it like this. Now, you _could_ do this by currying your method and parametrising over the other parameters, but I really don't recommend it

Comment: @joel fair point - but I have no plan to use them polymorphously and do `isinstance` checks, I only mention it for the sake of argument for the typechecker. My actual setup has ex. `PersonWithBicycle` and `PersonWithMotorcycle` classes, which only ever instantiate `Bicycle` and `Motorcycle`, so it's never a problem.

Comment: I'm not sure how else I would model the hierarchy differently - if I avoid making `update()` an abstractmethod, there is no need for the class `Bike`, which feels like a step in the wrong direction... there could be a better way though

Comment: Why would not needing a `class Bike` be "a step in the wrong direction"?

Comment: `Bike` may also have other methods (`ride()`, etc.) that I would want every subclass to inherit. Seems unlikely that the best solution is removing the superclass. Looking at this again today, I'm wondering if there's some trick where I could add another method `_update()` and type both differently. Will post again if I have a solution.